# Identifying most suitable dependent rpm packages

Tags: dependency-management, rpm, yum

Not sure SO is the best place to ask this, but it is development related so maybe someone can help.

I've written an app (in python but that's not important) which parses a Yum repo database to collate RPM packages and their dependencies. The problem I have is that I am sucking in too many packages when a dependency is met by more than one.

Specific example: I am seeking the list of packages which meet dependencies for Java-1.8.0 and getting a dependency of libjli.so()(64bit). libjli.so()(64bit) My code correctly works out that this is provided by multiple -devel packages from the Java 1.8, 1.7 and 1.6 streams. Unfortunately all three versions (and their dependencies) then get included in my list.

I guess my question is, given a list of packages meeting a requirement, what is the best way to identify the most appropriate package to include? i.e. when resolving the dependencies for Java-1.8.0, only include the -devel package for 1.8.0 and not suck in the -devel packages for 1.6 and 1.7 as well.

I know this is a problem with my code, I'm just not sure what facilities are provided by the yum ecosystem to help me identify which package would be best to include from the list of multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is hard to tell without seeing your code.
2. Yum is dead. If you are developing something new, you should develop on top of DNF. DNF use satsolver algorithm (https://doc.opensuse.org/projects/satsolver/11.4/index.html) and you can use libdnf https://github.com/rpm-software-management/libdnf (formerly known as libhif, formerly known as libhawkey).

Comment: I've made some progress. I'm querying the SQLite databases hosted by the repos directly and realised that for requirements, my queries were returning all packages which meet that requirement. I figured that if the packager hasn't specified a version, then by rights any version should work, so I pick the most recent by simply sorting the results of the query by package version and picking the highest.

Comment: you mention yum is dead. I was aware of that, but using RHEL, this is something I figured I would need to consider in the future. Are the upstream repo's changing as well or will they continue to use the same database structure on the back end? I mention yum repo database but I guess I just mean repo database...

Comment: As much as I hate asking "how do you do x" questions without at least trying to solve the problem myself, it looks like my c. 1000 lines of python are mostly pointless - hawkeye and librepo look, at first glance, like they do everything I am trying to do. Oh well, my original goal was to speed up a process which parsed RPM files directly (and slowly) and I guess I taught myself some python in the process

Comment: Yes, the repo structure (and sqlite db) stay the same.

Comment: I ended up refactoring the code to use libhawkey, I appreciate that is deprecated, but it appears to be what's available out of the box in RHEL 7 (FC21?)